# xpath not finding text inside <div><span>

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
.//*[contains(text(), "Apply")]
```

```html
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="needsValidation"/>
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="fullValidationPerformed"/>
<div class="loadingBox hidden">
<div class="paneContent">
<div class="topButtons">
    <div class="rightSide">
    <div id="saveChangesButton" class="majorButton">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <span class="hidden"/>
                    Apply Changes
                    <span class="down"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is it that the xpath string I created doesn't find "Apply" here? It appears that my xpath statement only fails when the text I want to find is inside a "span" tag inside a "div" tag like this.

Can someone help me understand what I'm missing here please?

Comment: change the text() with . (period)

Comment: "change the text with . (period)?" I don't understand. Can you explain a little more please

Comment: Is your test attempting to find the button to click or are asserting that the text includes the word "Apply"? Check out https://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium/css-selectors for a great cheat sheet on Selenium selectors.

Comment: .//*[contains(text(), "Apply")] should be like this : .//*[contains(., "Apply")]

Comment: @poodled - that works, except it returns 7 matching nodes - every node that contains a node that contains this string. i.e., the form node, each div node that contain a div node that contains, eventually, the string "Apply Changes". I know I can use an index to get to the desired node, but I'm trying to make this as implementation-independent as possible so if the developers change the UI implementation, we don't have a much work to do to update our test scripts.

Comment: @hubbardr - thanks! looks interesting.

Comment: ? You have 7 buttons that say Apply Changes? Do they all match the html you provided above? Maybe you should give us some more context from the actual markup?

Comment: @hubbardr, indeed there are 7 elements whose string value contains the string 'Apply': all the ancestors of the relevant text node.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that `contains(text(), 'Apply')` does not work is that the element has several text nodes, and the contains function in XPath 1.0 ignores all but the first. (XPath 2.0 would give you an error if there is more than one).

If you want to get an element whose string value contains 'Apply' without also returning its ancestors, the simplest way is to get the last element containing this string:

```
(//*[contains(., 'Apply')])[last()]
```